Question re: Replacing Some AC System Components
FWIW, my vehicle is a 2007 4-Runner 6-cyl Limited 2WD, but my question is more about what to do for my situation than specifically how to do it.
Over last few summers when my AC system seemed to be struggling during hottest periods I used some of the commonly available and well reviewed "top-off" products, e.g. AC Pro whatever.  But apparently the "Stop-Leak" additives they include/tout are no bueno for most (maybe all?) AC systems.  So I think I want (or should?) to evacuate/purge system completely and replace with new/fresh refrigerant.
So my main question is since I will have system open and evacuated, what else should I do?  Replacing the receiver drier is a no-brainer, but some other thoughts:
-- Use system flush just because (even if I don't replace compressor)?
-- Add some leak detection dye when I recharge with new refrigerant just so I can look around later?
-- Go ahead and replace condenser since it is fairly straight forward and not horribly expensive?
-- Go ahead and replace expansion valve since it is fairly straight forward and not horribly expensive?
-- What about replacing compressor on a prophylactic basis?  While I don't drive this car very hard at all (normal driving; drive it maybe 8K miles a year at most; sometimes tow a utility trailer), car is 17 years old and I am getting old enough that doing some of this in 5 or 10 years from now would be a problem for me, so that's a real consideration.
I don't want to do anything that is truly useless or just to say I did it, but I honestly am not sure what qualifies for that vs. "should do".
Depressingly, I've noticed that a lot of OEM (Denso) products for my car are on near permanent backorder nationally here in U.S.  Not sure why or if using non-OEM for AC parts is a good idea.

In plain language, you made the mistake of using leak sealer, effectively ruining what should have been a thorough leak search (with dye and/or electronic leak sniffer), replace any parts, used new seals where fittings were separated, replaced the combination accumulator/receiver/drier, evacuated the system and made a final leak check observing both gauges after shutting off the vacuum pump and isolating the system to gauges only. Whether you know it or not, sealer basically circulates throughout a system and reacts to moisture to create an internal seal. Every ac system is assembled, evacuated completely of any air and moisture, leak checked before installing refrigerant. No air or moisture is allowed with minute amounts absorbed in the desiccant in the canister next to the condenser coil. A lifetime seal until damage occurs. Sealer in a compromised system means moisture may have entered and react to seal; passages, thermal expansion valve, compressor, condenser coil, evaporator coil, fittings, and hoses. I doubt any repair shop uses sealer in repairs because they know better. Best case scenario with sealer is flushing the entire system of all oil and sealer, if sealer can be removed (if it already sealed passages). Dismantling the system for flushing may be the only way to ensure everything is flushed and free of sealer blockage. Not a small task to ensure condenser coils aren't blocked, filter/drier isn't blocked, thermal expansion valve isn't blocked, etc., preventing free flow of refrigerant. I wouldn't want to be in your shoes as I never use sealer in diy repairs. BTW, condenser coils are not flow thru tube types as in r12 systems. Flat tubes made to run parallel as opposed to tubing flowing from end to end, serpentine fashion. If sealer impedes flow, this can be a reduction in flow and cooling hot refrigerant. I think the evaporator coils are serpentine tube configuration.
There is one site in Arizona, a parts distributor for everything ac, that had snapshots of sealer, resembling foam, clogging/blocking various ac parts in their public ac forums for anyone discussing vehicle ac problems. They've updated their website and those images may be in archival records, requiring an extensive search in their site.
Unfortunately, none of manufacturer's ac refill kits provide guarantee of success or money back with some stating trying another can and if unsuccessful.....seek out professional services. Caveat emptor. I use a simple analogy of comparing turbo/supercharging to vehicle ac repairs; if a person doesn't know how to diagnose, troubleshoot and repair turbo/supercharging systems, ac systems are just as complicated. Both are not diy friendly unless having more than casual familiarity.

Thanks.  Yeah, re: Top-off/Stop-Leak products, it's really frustrating for a typical driver/DIYer...this stuff is pushed at us everywhere (Oreillys, Autozone, Lowes Depot, Amazon, NAPA, AdvanceAutoParts, Walmart, etc.) and they make it so easy with the filler tube and gauge.  Oh well...live and learn :--/

The only time I would use a leak sealer is if I wasn't going to spend the money to ever repair it. I would try it in a last ditch effort, realizing that if it works, great, if it doesn't there will be no more AC for this vehicle. If it was too expensive to fix beforehand, it's definitely too expensive afterward.

@Jupiter: "The only time I would use a leak sealer..."  Yes, I now understand after much discussion and research.  What Is really hard to figure out is why virtually all the DIY re-charge (a.k.a. "top-off") kits and products (e.g. AC Pro)...shelves upon shelves of them in all the auto stores & departments, taut some sort of leak sealer and other additives.  You pretty much can't get one with it and it's just shocking they are so ubiquitous if one accepts the stop leak stuff is no good for typical AC system.

If you are having to top off your system every summer then you have a leak, and you should fix it, for one thing refrigerant is bad for the environment, but mainly because over time it will get worse and maybe more expensive.
Stop leak products can work, but really are only a stopgap measure even if they do, which is plainly not the case for you. I would not start replacing parts until you determine where the leak is, unless you love spending money and time for no reason. I would investigate to find the leak, and look at the general condition of the system. If the products you have used have a dye in them then you can look for it with a UV light. If it's a very slow leak or  it's pointing the wrong way (the dye has to land on something for you to see it, if it's spraying into open space it's not going to show anything) then the dye will not help you. If you can't see dye then pressurizing the system with air or better yet nitrogen gas and using diluted soap spray is the way to go.
Do yourself a favor and buy a manifold gauge, there's plenty of inexpensive ones available and they take the guesswork out of it. Replacing the dryer-receiver is always a good idea after fixing a leak as moisture will have worked its way into your system. You should also replace all your o-rings. If you can't find a Denso there are plenty of other decent brands like Mahle to choose from, or buy a refurbished one from a reputable shop.

"...and you should fix it..."  Yes, totally agreed, after all the research and discussion I've done.  The good news is I have serendipitously found a local guy with great reputation who will do am AC system check and diagnosis for a pittance, simply because he likes doing this stuff and staying busy and helping people.  He, smartly, asked that I first do a good cleaning and maintenance on condenser, radiator, and evaporator coils, plus new cabin filter if the current one needs it.  So those are next on my task list, hopefully this weekend, for this troubleshooting effort.

If it were me, I would check the AC pressures carefully before you open the system and see if they meet the performance requirements. You can find R134a pressure charts online readily that give acceptable low and high side pressure for given ambient conditions. If the system is partially clogged and/or the compressor is underperforming, you'll see this reflected in pressures (a clogged condenser, for example, would lead to high system pressure on the entire system, as the system struggles to reject heat. A weak compressor would show up as low pressure on the high pressure side as it struggles to increase the pressure). If the pressures look ok, I wouldn't replace anything. Just find the leak, replace the dryer, evacuate and recharge using pure R-134a.
Side note - I believe your 4Runner uses a mechanical fan clutch, not an electric fan, typical of older RWD vehicles. The fan clutch actuates based on the engine coolant temperature and is not directly monitoring the A/C system. If the engine is not hot the airflow through the radiator and condenser will be low even if the A/C system needs more, and you'll get subpar A/C performance. I've found this to be the case in other vehicles I've owned with fan clutches. There may not be anything wrong with your system.
Side note 2 - If you are adding refrigerant without a manifold gauge, you can easily overfill which will also reduce cooling performance. You really need a manifold gauge (that monitors both low and high side pressure, not that dinky freebie gauge from Autozone that shows only low pressure).
